# Computing the absolute value of a signed 32-bit two’s complement integer with bitwise operators

Tags: binary-operations, bit-strings

solution:

```
int iabs(int a) {
   int t = a >> 31;
   a = (a^t) - t;
   return a;
}
```

Can someone explain at the math level why shifting  31 bits to the right, xoring this result  with t and subtracting t from this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a programming question than a math one. Note that the right shift `>>` is sign-extending in the **C** language. Then, assuming an `int` is 32-bit wide:

```
                   // if a >= 0          // if a < 0

int t = a >> 31;   // t = 0              // t = 0xFFFFFFFF = -1
a = (a^t) - t;     // a = (a^0)-0 = a    // a = (a^(-1))-(-1) = ~a + 1 = -a
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]  Strictly speaking, the right-shift behavior is implementation defined in both [C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic) and [C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic), though (***emphasis*** mine):

> For negative a, the value of a >> b is implementation-defined (***in most implementations, this performs arithmetic right shift***, so that the result remains negative).

This is, however, a matter better suited to discuss next door at stackoverflow.com.

Comment: So if we have  a = -2 = 110 then 110>> 2 = 001 , 110 xor 001 = 111 and 7 - 1 != 2. Why did I do wrong. I think it has something to do with your sign extending claim.

Comment: @Dan It does. Assuming a 3-bit `int` as you have here, `0x110 >> 2` produces `0x111`. It’s an *arithmetic* shift, not a *logical* shift.

Comment: @Dan In a 3-bit two's-complement representation `110 >> 1 = 111` under most implementations (see the edit at the end). In 32-bit `-2 = 1111 1111 1111 1110` and `-2 >> 31 = 1111 1111 1111 1111`.